# What's the difference between dd and cat for writing image files?

Tags: linux, shell, dd, disk-image

When writing image files to disk or to a USB stick, the instructions usually use `dd`, like this:

```
dd if=myimage.img of=/dev/sdb
```

How is this different from, say:

```
cat myimage.img > /dev/sdb
```

I realize that `dd` has many more options, like `count=...`, but if the purpose of the exercise is to write an entire file to a device, what's the advantage of using `dd`?

Answer (score 11):

This question is like "I have this one tool that can draw rectangles and the other that can draw rhombuses; which one is the right tool to draw a square?"

Any square is a special case of rectangle and a special case of rhombus, so either one of the two tools can be used.

The same is with `dd` and `cat`. The former can do conversion, skip and seek, adjust buffer size; but in the simple case it just reads one file (or block device) and writes raw data to the other. The latter can concatenate multiple files into one stream with some optional textual modifications, but in the simple case there's just one input file the content of which is streamed (with the shell support) to the output file or device.

Both tools are useful and none can be discarded in favor of the other. Their scopes just overlap at this simple case you ask about.

---

**Having said that, I think there are at least two issues that make `dd` <strike>the better</strike> a reasonable choice.**

### 1. Block device permissions

To write to a file or device `cat` needs its output to be redirected. Your shell does the redirection i.e. opens the target file. While redirecting to `/dev/sdb` you will probably hit "permission denied" unless you are logged in as *root*. Running a shell as *root* is risky and should be avoided.

You may try

```
sudo cat myimage.img > /dev/sdb
```

and fail because `sudo` doesn't affect output redirection done by the shell.

On the other hand **this is completely non-problematic:**

```
sudo dd if=myimage.img of=/dev/sdb
```

A little hint by the way: if you find yourself in a situation where you must redirect the output to a file with restricted access then you may use this trick:

```
some_command | sudo tee restricted_file > /dev/null
```

That leads us to yet another way to do the job. The command `tee` passes its input to multiple files and to standard output. In simple case there is one file and the standard output is discarded:

```
sudo tee /dev/sdb < myimage.img > /dev/null
```

In this case there is also input redirection not affected by `sudo`.

### 2. Stepping beyond simple case

Imagine a carpenter who makes kitchen tables. Most tables have rectangular top surfaces; rhombus shaped ones are far less common. There is a table with square top to be made. A square is a rhombus, also it is a rectangle. Will the carpenter use methods that apply to rare rhombus shaped tables? or to common rectangular tables? Both sets of methods should work with square table, nevertheless he makes rectangles every single workday, so there is no point in changing the approach.

Back to `cat` and `dd`. In my opinion (and my practice) there is hardly ever a need to concatenate several images in order to write them all to block device. That definitely would be a job for `cat`. The tool can do something more but you don't want it: the options target text files so they can invalidate your binary data when used with image file.

Now, the options provided by `dd` are often useful to me when I read from or write to a device:

- <strike>`conv=noerror` – when the source may be faulty;</strike> actually no, [do not use `conv=sync,noerror`](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690); when the source may be faulty [use GNU `ddrescue`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/572247/108618);
- `bs=…` – large buffer won't exhaust my HDD;
- `count=…` – to read a fragment, like MBR;
- `conv=sparse` – to reduce image size in some circumstances.

There's more. This command:

```
kill -s USR1 $(pidof dd)
```

makes `dd` print I/O statistics to standard error. I don't think you can do this with `cat`.

These are the reasons **I consider `dd` to be the natural tool for working with raw images.** I see no point in changing the tool to `cat` just because there's no difference in some special case, **but I see another reason (below)**. I'd like to think the instructions usually use `dd` because their authors think like me. There is some elegance in ability to consciously choose *the right tool*, especially when there are more that seem equally suitable.

Still **[`dd` is a cranky tool which is hard to use correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121888/108618). Anyone's ability to consciously choose the right tool should include being aware of this fact.** If you're not sure you can use `dd` correctly then probably the right tool *for you* is not `dd`.

If you're sure you can use `dd` correctly then mind the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) and ask yourself again. :)

---

At the end I admit I have used `pv myimage.img | sudo tee /dev/sdb > /dev/null`. I abandoned my right tool but `pv` gave me a progress bar. <strike>Unless you need to concatenate `cat` gives nothing</strike>. **`cat` gives simplicity and protects you from pitfalls the cranky `dd` brings. For this reason alone it may be *your right tool*.** In some cases it's my right tool.

The important thing is: whenever I use `dd`, `cat` or whatever for the task in question, it's a *tool of choice*, conscious choice.