# How can I run dd as fast as possible?

Tags: linux, bash, dd

I'm learning `bash`, and what with all the confusion around the many, *many* different ways there are to zero-write a drive or transfer data from/to one (`shred` vs `dd` vs `pv` vs `cat` vs `tee` and so on), I'm already overwhelmed.

For now, I've reluctantly opted for `dd` as it seems the best command-line option out there for both uses. Given that, I want to be sure I'm using it as efficiently as possible.

I understand that by default `dd` runs with a block size of 512 bytes, and that increasing this with something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=3M status=progress
```

...will make it write larger blocks and do so fewer times, therefore resulting in a faster run.

But if simply setting a larger block size will make the command run faster, what's to stop me from using `bs=3G`? What are the disadvantages to doing so, if any? What is the optimal block size Linux superusers would recommend using?

Comment: Just having a larger block size isn't the answer, the most efficient block size can very by hardware, RAM, processor, other applications, etc... There is an article and script for testing/finding the right combination somewhere, I will see if I can find the link.

Comment: Ahh... here it is... Not really an answer, but it might put you on the right track... http://blog.tdg5.com/tuning-dd-block-size/

Comment: @Vlastimil: It really makes no difference if you use `dd`, `pv` or `cp`: They *all* run as fast as the hardware allows. And please don't spread nonsense like "dd is obsolete for disk zeroing": `dd` is a particular tool with particular uses, and while it's old, "obsolete" has nothing to do with this. You use whatever tools works best in your scenario.

Comment: "with all the confusion around the many, many different ways there are…" – You may find this question interesting: [*What's the difference between dd and cat for writing image files?*](https://superuser.com/q/944603/432690)

Answer (score -1):

The tool called [hdparm](https://tinyapps.org/docs/wipe_drives_hdparm.html) might be something you can look into. It is a very low-level tool and has some potentially dangerous options. Here is the [man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/hdparm) page for the tool. It is powerful so use it at your own risk. A zero-write will probably be fastest performed by this tool.

Comment: Do you have any sources or reasoning to corroborate the claim that `hdparm` would be a faster tool than all those mentioned in my question?

Comment: Check the links I added for documentation on the tool. The only method I know for testing the speed and time taken for a zero-write is to use different tools on the same test HDD and using the `time` command to see the performance times. The blue words in my answer are links to information on the tool. From what I can tell, it is written in assembler which is going to be the fastest execution. Next step up would be C/C++. You just have to test different tools out.