# How does dd know about correct disk label when burning iso to usb?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, arch-linux, iso-image, bootable-media, dd

I used `dd` to burn arch linux image to usb stick, but now I need to store additional files on the same usb stick. The usb stick is read-only after `dd` so I decided to format it manually. The stick was recognized as bootable but the arch failed to load the system since it was looking for a disk labeled "ARCH_201912". As far as I know I can use `-n` flag with `mkfs.fat` command like this:

```
mkfs.fat -F 32 -n "$label" "$partition"
```

I just do not want to type it manually as it changes every month (I am writing bash function). And `dd` somehow knows what the label should be and correctly set it to usb device. I thought there is a file storing this value, so I issued:

```
$ grep --directories=recurse ARCH_201912 .

./arch/boot/syslinux/archiso_pxe.cfg:APPEND archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201912 archiso_nbd_srv=${pxeserver}
./arch/boot/syslinux/archiso_sys.cfg:APPEND archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201912
Binary file ./EFI/archiso/efiboot.img matches
./loader/entries/archiso-x86_64.conf:options archisobasedir=arch archisolabel=ARCH_201912
```

Is there a way to get this label without parsing the file (as it seems that `archisolabel` is specific for arch linux)? I want this method work both for linux and windows. Though I am not sure if windows 10 require proper label set.

Comment: Follow this wiki word by word: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_flash_installation_media

Comment: It would be nice if you point to some paragraph or section. Actually, I have read this guide. Not all because I do not need an installation method on mac os or windows. Only sections describing `dd` method and manual formatting.

Comment: Afaik, you do not have to create partitions or format it since `dd` already do it for you. But I stated that I need extra files on the same media like installation guide. `dd` marks drive as read-only, so I decided to manually format the drive and copy image files with `cp`. It works great due to EFI boot, but I have to manually set label which arch linux require.

Comment: `dd` knows nothing. If you are asked to copy a book and you're precise enough, you will be able to do this even if you don't know the language or the alphabet. `dd` just copies bytes from one place to another. What you did probably [could be done with `cat`](https://superuser.com/q/944603/432690) or `cp`. These tools also know nothing. The label is there because it's inside the superblock of the filesystem or something. You can copy a book you cannot understand and if someone asks how did you know the main character's name, the answer will be [mu](http://catb.org/jargon/html/M/mu.html).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, so it is up to maintainer of the .iso file to make it `dd`able (like setting partitions or label)? This makes sense. I thought there could be kind of standard for EFI specifying label of the disk.

Comment: `dd`able? I don't understand. Every file is "`dd`able" because you can copy it. Not every file makes sane content for a USB pendrive though. I don't know EFI standards but if you copied the image to the entire device and it turned out some EFI partition appeared on it, then it means the partition table and the partition was inside the image. I'm not really sure what you did with `dd` (there is no *exact* `dd` command in the question) and later (format it manually – how?), so I cannot replicate the problem. Alongside describing, post the actual commands you used.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, sorry, I meant `dd`able in terms of booting from usb. My question apparently cannot be answered as there is no file structure/layout I was looking for. I was looking only for label value stored in e.g. /boot/loader/label.txt or something easy to catch.

Comment: Usually those ISO images are so-called hybrid images: looking for an iso9660 signature with an El-Torito boot? Here it is, boot this CD. Looking for a MBR with its boot? Here it is too, boot as disk in BIOS mode. looking for a GPT partition-scheme with an EFI boot partition? Here you are. Boot as disk from UEFI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And dd somehow knows what the label should be and correctly set it to usb device

The label is not actually set on the device in any special way. It is simply part of the filesystem metadata (which itself is stored as regular data), and gets blindly copied along with all other filesystem structures.

> dd marks drive as read-only,

It doesn't. If that happens, either it's at filesystem level (maybe the image only contained a filesystem that does not support writing, e.g. ISO9660 is read-only by design), or the drive has physically reached end-of-life (as cheap USB sticks often do).

> so it is up to maintainer of the .iso file to make it ddable (like setting partitions or label)?

Yes. A "pure" .iso file only contains the ISO9660 filesystem used by CDs – it's up to the maintainer to use tools to convert it into a hybrid image containing a BIOS MBR bootloader and a FAT32 or similar filesystem.

(Or the maintainer could of course skip the .iso part and just directly build a regular "dd-able" disk image from the beginning.)

> I thought there could be kind of standard for EFI specifying label of the disk.

Disks have no label. *Partitions* can have a label, as well as *filesystems.* The only thing about USB sticks is that they normally have just one partition (and one filesystem), so its label is often seen as the disk's label.

Both kinds of labels are stored on the disk itself, as regular data. (Partition labels are indeed stored in the UEFI GPT partition table, but you usually don't see them.)

Filesystem labels – the usual kind that you see – are stored in the filesystem metadata, e.g. in the Ext4 header or in the FAT32 master file table.

However, the label is **not** stored as an actual file – in FAT32 it is a special MFT record type; in other filesystems it is a dedicated filesystem header field.

> Is there a way to get this label without parsing the file (as it seems that archisolabel is specific for arch linux)?

On Linux you'll want to use *libblkid*, which has a corresponding CLI tool `blkid`. The library can extract basic information (filesystem label, UUID) from dozens of filesystem types.

However, blkid requires root privileges in order to read physical devices, so you'll want to get the cached data from udev using `lsblk`, leaving `blkid` for image files.

```
lsblk -n -o LABEL /dev/sda2
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Yes, it seems like arch linux uses ISO 9660 filesystem - "To restore the USB drive as an empty, usable storage device after using the Arch ISO image, the ISO 9660 filesystem signature needs to be removed by running ...".