# How can I recreate an installer iso from a usb (Mac/Windows) using dd?

Tags: windows-10, macos, usb-flash-drive, dd

I have read many "how do I write an iso to USB" questions. I am looking for a way to reverse the process. My question is about taking a USB stick containing a Windows installer or Mac installer and using `dd` to read only those parts of the USB that are needed to recreate the original iso.

Scenario:
I have a Windows 10 October 2020 edition USB that I burned back in November. I want to back that up to disk using `dd`. Something along the lines of:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=backup-windows.iso bs=4m
```

I would like to be able to compare this with the original iso and get a match. In other words, I don't want to have to make a 64 GB image of a USB drive when the ISO is only 7-8GB.

Comment: In Windows there's the free ImageUSB, https://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html , that can go from USB to ISO. Regrettably, I did not find such a tool for Mac or Linux, but see https://osxdaily.com/2020/07/20/how-convert-macos-installer-iso/ for roundabout MacOS instructions.

Comment: I don't have a Windows installer to test this with, but Disk Utility ought to be able to do this. File Menu>New Image. I tested with a Mojave installer, 6GB on a 20GB partition & set the 'Compressed' attribute. Files saved was 6GB [very slightly smaller than the original data] https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JT1A.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preliminary note

This answer introduces commands valid in POSIX-compliant or almost POSIX-compliant operating systems, in particular in Linux or macOS. Commands are not for pure Windows (but I suppose the answer can be adjusted to work in WSL or Cygwin).

---

#### Analysis

OK, you have copied some image to a USB drive `/dev/sdx`. In general you cannot exactly reverse the process basing solely on the content and properties of the drive because you don't know how many bytes to read. The upper bound is the size of the drive (64 GB in your case), everything else is a guess. The drive contains a stream of bytes and there is no mark saying "stop reading here to get the original image".

By analyzing the partition table (if any) it's possible to take an educative guess. But even then you cannot be sure the original image was not larger (with garbage or non-garbage at the end).

However you want to compare the result to some other image, let's call it `the_other_file`. I guess you hope the two images will be identical. To be identical they must be of the same size. This means you know how many bytes to read from `/dev/sdx`: the exact number of bytes `the_other_file` has. You can get this number by invoking

```
wc -c /path/to/the_other_file
```

or

```
</path/to/the_other_file wc -c
```

Note the former is a standalone command while the latter requires a shell (to handle `<`). From now on I assume you're in a shell.

---

#### Copying

If your ultimate goal is to compare then you *don't need* to copy to a regular file. Read the whole answer before you decide. Still the explicit question is:

> How can I recreate an installer iso from a usb […] using `dd`?

It seems [`dd` is the only POSIX way to read an exact number of bytes from a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278465/108618). The way requires `ibs=1`, it can be slow. To read `N` bytes:

```
dd ibs=1 count=N if=/dev/sdx of=image_file
```

The resulting file is `image_file`.

The original image, as an image designed to be written to a block device, most likely was of a size that is multiple of 512 bytes, possibly a multiple of 4096 bytes. You probably can use some bigger `ibs` then.

If `N` is an *exact* multiple of some bigger `ibs` you want to use then you can use the bigger `ibs` with `count` adjusted. The number after `count=` specifies how many blocks of the size `ibs` to read. Notes:

- `bs` specifies both `ibs` and `obs` (see `man 1 dd`).
- Neither `bs=4m` (from your example) nor `bs=4M` belong to the [POSIX specification of `dd`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html). The valid suffixes are `k` and `b`. You may be surprised the specification also allows strings in a form of `AxB`. To get 4 MiB use `bs=4kx1k`; to get 4 MB use `bs=4000000` or `bs=4000x1000` etc.
- In general keep in mind `dd` is a cranky tool which is hard to use correctly. There are pitfalls. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121865/108618) and [this](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/432690).

If `N` is not an exact multiple of some bigger `ibs` you want to use, it's possible to read the majority of what you want to read with the large `ibs` and append the missing part while reading with `ibs=1`. This is cumbersome, requires some calculations, still it's technically possible; hardly ever useful though. If you are not limited to POSIX, there are better ways.

GNU `dd` supports `iflag=count_bytes` that makes `count` count bytes regardless of `ibs`. Along with `iflag=fullblock` it makes `dd` a decent tool to read an exact number of bytes. In your case the command could be:

```
dd bs=4M iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count=N if=/dev/sdx of=image_file
```

or (to avoid typing `N` manually):

```
dd bs=4M iflag=fullblock,count_bytes count="$(</path/to/the_other_file wc -c)" if=/dev/sdx of=image_file
```

If I were you I would use `head -c`:

```
head -c "$(</path/to/the_other_file wc -c)" /dev/sdx >image_file
```

Note `wc -c` is portable (specified by POSIX) but `head -c` is not (although I believe `head` in macOS supports `-c`).

---

#### Comparing

You can compare directly, without creating any `image_file`. The following command is portable:

```
cmp /dev/sdx /path/to/the_other_file
```

In your case `/dev/sdx` is a device larger than `the_other_file`. You will get either a message (to stdout) the files differ, or a message (to stderr) `EOF on the_other_file`. In either case the exit status will be `1`. The latter message means the beginning of `/dev/sdx` is identical to `the_other_file`. This is what you would expect after copying `the_other_file` to `/dev/sdx`.

If you want to judge by the exit status (useful in scripting) then you need to make sure you're comparing files of equal sizes. This is still possible without creating any `image_file`:

```
head -c "$(</path/to/the_other_file wc -c)" /dev/sdx | cmp - /path/to/the_other_file
```

(The exit status of a pipeline comes from the last command; here: from `cmp`.) Note `head -c` is (still `:)`) not portable. You can replace it with portable `dd …` if needed:

```
dd ibs=1 count="$(</path/to/the_other_file wc -c)" if=/dev/sdx | cmp - /path/to/the_other_file
```

Alternatively after creating `image_file` as shown above, you can straightforwardly compare `image_file` to `the_other_file`:

```
cmp image_file the_other_file
```

Exit status `0` indicates the files are identical; exit status `1` indicates the files are not identical.

While working interactively you can pay attention to the output instead (I mean stdout + stderr, i.e. all what you normally see in a terminal). Empty output from `cmp` indicates the files are identical; non-empty output from `cmp` indicates whatever it says. Note `dd` (but not `head`) prints to stderr even if there was no error. I deliberately wrote "empty output *from `cmp`*", not just "empty output". When in doubt, check the exit status anyway: run `echo $?` just after `cmp` (or after a pipeline ending with `cmp`).